# JavaFX Image: Check if image is valid

Tags: image, javafx, exception

I have written a small JavaFX application with many configurations. One of them is, that you can define inside of a config-file which images you want to use.

Now I wanted to add error-handling for every case, but I don't know how to check, if a specific Image is drawable.

I already know, how to check for the existence of a Image, now I just want to know, how to check, if javafx would draw my Image or just do nothing.

```
Image img = new Image("file:corrupted.png");
gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

In this case, no exception is thrown and gc just draws nothing.

```
if (!img.isValid()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

I want to do something like the code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to detect for errors during loading of `Image`.

From [`Image.errorProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#errorProperty):

> Indicates whether an error was detected while loading an image.

If you need to know what caused an error, you can use this:

From [`Image.exceptionProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#exceptionProperty):

> The exception which caused image loading to fail. Contains a non-null value only if the error property is set to true.

If your `Image` is constructed with a constructor overload that loads in the background, then you can also use [`Image.progressProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#progressProperty) to check that the image has completed loading. If `image.getProgress() == 1 && !image.isError()` is `true`, then you can be sure that there is a valid image.

Comment: `img.isError()` worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!